# Unity Facebook SDK official example - FB.Init not working

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I cannot get both my own game using the SDK and the example Unity project provided by Facebook to work.

I have the Unity3D file uploaded and linked in the app settings. Upon clicking the "FB.Init" button, the console states: "Facebook DLL: Not loaded". Therefore, I am unable to login.

Pressing the button again provides this message: "FB.Init() has already been called.  You only need to call this once and only once." If I force the login, I get this error: "NullReferenceException: Facebook object is not yet loaded.  Did you call FB.Init()?"

This is also the same when testing on an iOS device.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you add the App id in the editor-> facebook?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem.

The host service that is storing my Unity build was being blocked by my browser script blocker. Though the game still ran fine, I was unable to use any of the Facebook SDK functionality with it blocked.

School boy error, but solved nonetheless.